# Word 2010 documents open as small windows, not full screen

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-word

When I open Word 2010 documents by clicking the document name in my file folders, they open as half-screen sizes, not full screen. They do respond to my clicking the center box on the upper right to  become full screen. But why should I have to? I want them to open full screen to begin with and I can't find any option in the File menu that deals with this.

Answer (score 5):

Right click on the word icon, select properties and then Run "Maximised". See the images.

[image: Properties q]

[image: Properties 2]

Comment: With Windows 10, the properties window can be accessed from the taskbar by right-clicking on the program icon and then, right-clicking again on the program icon in the pop-up.

Answer (score 3):

Word should remember the size, position and status of the last time you used the application.

So if, when you double click a document, Word opens a non-full screen window make it maximized and then **close Word**.

The next time you open Word it should remember that and open maximized.

If that doesn't work, try opening Word from the menu/desktop, maximize and then close.

Comment: I had a similar issue in Excel 2013 64-bit. I thought the issue was an add-in I'm developing, but completely closing Excel fixed the issue for me. Closing that specific file had no effect; it wasn't until I closed the entire application that it worked. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 3):

The 'Hold Control button' while closing out of maximized Word Doc worked for me! (so far, anyways)... Also worked for Outlook and opening email docs.
I have Win & and Office 2010

Answer (score 0):

In Windows (I believe XP and above), you can set the default window size by holding the control key and exiting the program.  For example, to get MS Word to open your documents in full screen by default: open a document, maximize it, hold ctrl and click the "X" to close it.  This will save that window's size and position (be it maximized or any other position and size you have set) and use it as the default for that program.  This should also work for any other program that does not implement its own custom size setting parameters (i.e. command prompt).

Answer (score 0):

Open a word document, then maximize the window size **"manually"** ,

> not by clicking the maximize button on the right top corner.

Then close the window by clicking "x" button on the right top corner.This will not solve your problem %100 but, at least you will keep the size that your manual size for your next windows.

Otherwise, as I know you should play with the registry codes by using regeditor of Windows.